# Symfony/Doctrine: "Soft update" if a certain field has changed

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I know you can soft delete in Doctrine (i.e. do not delete a record but rather add a "deleted" value). There's an extension for that.

Now I wonder if there's a way to "soft update" a record. I mean not actually update the record but rather create a new record and make the old one invalid. In the same extension as soft-delete, there's a function `loggable`, but this one logs to a different table.

- I could create a controller that, instead of updating, soft-deletes
  (and thus invalidates) the old record, and then creates a new one
  with the new values. But I'm unsure if this is a good practice.
- Maybe I should create this action on the object itself? But I'm
  unsure how to do this.

### Edit

I've looked into Versionable and EntityAudit (as suggested by Tomas), but it seems these bundles do way too much. I merely want to check if a given field is different from the old one, and if not: soft-delete the old one (I'm using softDeleteable so a simple `remove()` will do); then create a new one with the changed values.

So ideally it would lurk in the shadows until an update is performed. Then read from the mapping configuration which fields it needs to watch, and if these fields are indeed different from what's persisted, the program should execute the `remove()` and `persist()` commands.

Comment: Sounds more like a feature request for said extension

Comment: Hi there bluppfisk. The answers you might receive on a question like this could be opinionated. I understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you have an example of what you might delete or update, and then maybe we can understand the need for the delete?

Comment: Parts. Parts can be part of a Job. Parts can change in price, but that shouldn't change the Job.

Answer (score 1):

This extension might suit your use case:

- [simplethings/EntityAudit](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit)

It records any changes you want to track.
So it should be pretty easy to modify it to meed your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit new to Symfony but it seems this bundle does way too much. I merely want to check if a given field is different from the old one, and if not: soft-delete the old one (I'm using softDeleteable so a simple `remove()` will do); then create a new one with the changed values.

So ideally it would lurk in the shadows until an update is performed. Then read from the mapping configuration which fields it needs to watch, and if these fields are indeed different from what's persisted, the program should execute the `remove()` and `persist()` commands.

Comment: I understand your needs. You can use just the listener's code (that does the job) from the EntityAudit and modify it to your needs. Do you need help with anything else?

Comment: Hi Tomas. I've spotted the following limitation in EntityAudit: _Many-To-Many associations are NOT versioned_. But then I can't use it, because the Many-to-Many fields are the ones that are most important to my code.

I've been thinking that it must be a common thing to "soft-update". The lack of simple solutions make me suspect that my approach is completely wrong.

Comment: I completely agree with your last sentence. What do you need exactly this feature for?

Comment: I've explained it in full here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525756/doctrine-tracking-history-of-slowly-changing-dimensions

TLDR: to keep track of slowly changing dimensions in my order process.

Comment: Thank you for link. I'm sorry but this is way too complex to answer for me.