# Doctrine: tracking history of slowly changing dimensions

Tags: database-design, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm developing a type of web shop in Symfony3/Doctrine. In order to simplify things, let's say I have a table `Repairs` and one `Parts`. Parts have a name and a price, and a Repair can use many Parts, as well as various Parts can be used in various Repairs (Many-to-many). The price of a Repair is the sum of the prices of the Parts and some other factors.

**Slowly changing dimensions**

Now it should be possible to change the price of one `Part`, and this should change the price of future `Repairs`. However, any `Repairs` that already exist in the Database should not change, as they are used for accounting, invoicing and such.

**"Soft-updateable"**

Deleting a `Part` is easily solved with [SoftDeleteable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md). This keeps the relationships between `Parts` and `Repairs` intact. Something similar should happen for updating Entities. Only if something vital (such as the price) changes, the Entity should be updated in the database. However, there seems to be no ready-made code.

**I've tried the following:**

- Simply deleting the old Entity and storing a copy upon every update, which is code-intensive, inefficient and leaves lots of junk in the database.
- [Versionable](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/), but this does not work on many-to-many entities
- [Loggable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md), but this writes the changes in a separate log table, not in the table I'm using
- [EntityAudit](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit), but this also doesn't do what I want and can't be used on many-to-manies.

**Approach the problem differently?**

I've [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384988/symfony-doctrine-soft-update-if-a-certain-field-has-changed/38385317?noredirect=1#comment64441465_38385317) for help with my technical solutions [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423582/doctrine-on-persist-soft-delete-only-if-object-has-changed), but Since I believe that the problem is a common one, I'm starting to think that the lack of straightforward, ready-made solutions mean that I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way. Perhaps I should simply keep a static table for accounting with static values stored in them (but this would not allow changing the name of a certain Repair while keeping the price)? Or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: Your question it pretty broad, therefore there may be more then one good enough solution. This one below is just my opinion.

I think you should reconsider your domain. Think again about what the "price" actually is. As you've already noticed that it's varying depending on point of view. In your examples there were two cases:

- current (*base*) price of product.
- the price in the past at the time, the `Rapair` was made. (actually *paid* amount)

But there are even more points of view on the same price. The price may not only change over time, but it may have multiple values **at the same time**. Let's say, you want to implement discounts feature, where if `Parts` for a `Repair` cost >100$ in total, you give a 5% discount. In this case two clients may have different price at the same exact time.

Taking above into account, you could notice, that it's not actually matter of `Part`'s price over time, but there are two different price properties. One *base* price, and the second *paid* price.

Since *paid* price may have values that never existed as a *base* (e.g. in discount case), it's clear, that you're dealing with two different values that only by accidence can have the same name `price`. But they belong to two different entities.

**tl;dr**

You're dealing with two different values and they should be kept separately.

**Solution proposal**

Instead of `ManyToMany` relation, you could make an explicit entity `RepairPart`, which would relate to both `Repair` and `Part` entities in `ManyToOne` relation, but it will also contain additional data that you may need in the future, but they may change in source `Part` table. In this case it's the price.